# Apache cxf 3.2. response behavior

Tags: apache, cxf, cxfrs

**I am using Apache CXF version 3.0.4 and while hitting my rest call getting 400 as Bad request and complete stack trace through which i was able to do further logic**

**Now when i have upgraded my cxf version to 3.2.1/3.2.6 then only in response i can see 400 bad request but that Stack trace missed and not showing any thing in response.**

**Can any one please tell what has been changed in 3.2.(Apache CXF).? or do i need to do add anything to get the same behavior?.**

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper`](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/rt/frontend/jaxrs/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/impl/WebApplicationExceptionMapper.java). Setting `addMessageToResponse` to `true` should help.